# Why is 'é' and 'é' encoding to different bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, normalization

## Question

Why is the same character encoding to different bytes in different parts of my code base?

## Context

I have a unit test that generates a temporary file tree and then checks to make sure my scan actually finds the file in question.

```
def test_unicode_file_name():
    test_regex = "é"
    file_tree = {"files": ["é"]} # File created with python.open()
    with TempTree(file_tree) as tmp_tree:
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        result = tasks.find_files(test_regex, root_path=tmp_tree.root_path)
        expected = [os.path.join(tmp_tree.root_path, "é")]
        assert result == expected
```

## Function that's failing

```
for dir_entry in scandir(current_path):
    if dir_entry.is_dir():
        dirs_to_search.append(dir_entry.path)

    if dir_entry.is_file():
        testing = dir_entry.name
        if filename_regex.match(testing):
            results.append(dir_entry.path)
```

## PDB Session

When I started digging into things I found that the test character (copied from my unit test) and the character in `dir_entry.name` encoded to different bytes.

```
(Pdb) testing
'é'
(Pdb) 'é'
'é'
(Pdb) testing == 'é'
False
(Pdb) testing in 'é'
False
(Pdb) type(testing)
<class 'str'>
(Pdb) type('é')
<class 'str'>
(Pdb) repr(testing)
"'é'"
(Pdb) repr('é')
"'é'"
(Pdb) 'é'.encode("utf-8")
b'\xc3\xa9'
(Pdb) testing.encode("utf-8")
b'e\xcc\x81'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your operating system (MacOS, at a guess) has converted the filename `'é'` to [Unicode Normal Form D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normal_forms), decomposing it into an unaccented `'e'` and a combining acute accent. You can see this clearly with a quick session in the Python interpreter:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> e1 = b'\xc3\xa9'.decode()
>>> e2 = b'e\xcc\x81'.decode()
>>> [unicodedata.name(c) for c in e1]
['LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE']
>>> [unicodedata.name(c) for c in e2]
['LATIN SMALL LETTER E', 'COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT']
```

To ensure that you're comparing like with like, you can convert the filename given by `dir_entry.name` back to Normal Form C before testing it against your regex:

```
import unicodedata

for dir_entry in scandir(current_path):
    if dir_entry.is_dir():
        dirs_to_search.append(dir_entry.path)

    if dir_entry.is_file():
        testing = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', dir_entry.name)
        if filename_regex.match(testing):
            results.append(dir_entry.path)
```

Comment: Why use `NFC` instead of `NFD`? Does it matter which normalized format you go to?

Comment: NFC is more compact, and is the form that (quirky filesystem decisions by Apple aside) you'll find most often – for instance, it's obviously what you got when you typed `é` into your editor. It's also the form [recommended by W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/charmod-norm/#choice-of-normalization-form), for whatever that's worth.